# bootstrap grid: how can acheive a formation where i have two rows one below the other on left and one on their right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i achieve the following with bootstrap grid system?

```
..............................
.                  .         .
.  col-md-9(div1)  . col-md-3.
.................... (div2)  .
.                  .         .
.  col-md-9(div3)  .         .
....................         .
.                  ...........
.                            .
.                            .
..............................
```

i tried the following:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="col-md-9" style="float: left;">
</div>
```

this gave me something like this :

```
..............................
.                  .         .
.  col-md-9(div1)  . col-md-3.
.................... (div2)  .
.                  .         .
.                  .         .
.                  .         .
..............................
.                  .         .
.  col-md-9(div3)  .         .
..............................
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: See the [dashboard example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) for a way to do it. Basically you have to wrap div1 and div3 inside a row, itself inside a column.

Comment: so you mean like `col-md-9` inside that i have to make `div1 and div3` and then i am left with `col-md-3`... seems to do the required stuff. thanks.

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Comment: and yes it did worked. this was simple. thanks

Comment: Oh and by default all columns are floated left :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Test Left</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">Test Under Left</div>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Test Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the rough example. See http://www.bootply.com/8u0TlzECVR

Comment: You don't have to use sm. I just did for ease of testing since I'm on a laptop.

Comment: The nested rows are a bit unnecessary. Might be some sort of good practice, but you can get the same result without. See http://www.bootply.com/4HUK8T1DgO

Comment: Those are the Boostrap guidelines. Yea, you don't technically need the columns inside it to warrant a row, but I did to make it more obvious.